# Angular $viewContentLoaded event activoty range

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does $viewContentLoaded event include assets like images loading/rendering?

What i want to determine is that when i listen to this event can i be sure, that view is fully rendered and there will be no flickering or partial image rendering?

Or it just indicate when the html of the view is ready and inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the HTML of the view, unfortunately. AngularJS does not magically listen to the load event of every other resource on the page. Instead, it just blindly emits the `$viewContentLoaded` event once it appends and compiles the HTML.

You can [check out the source code for yourself](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L243).

Comment: So basically if I want to be sure, that all resources are ready, I have to manually listen to load event of each of them. Mayby a custom directive is a solution...?

Comment: It will be tricky to determine when you are fully loaded, because lots of things can cause further rendering to be done - timeouts, images specified in CSS, third party code, lazy loaded images, network calls that return data that then has to be rendered, etc. If possible, think of another solution than going down that path to solve your particular problem.

Comment: I think about a simple view with some static images and simple animations, so none of  CSS background or other mentioned stuff should make a problem