# AngularJS - How to set a scope variable array dynamically on opening a pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a view which is populating the data set by a scope variable `properties` using `ng-repeat`.

I have a button which opens a pop up on its click.

On opening a pop up, I want to use the same view but want to change its content i.e. (just want to change the scope array variable 'properties' content).

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in properties track by $index" id="{{ prop.id }}">
<h6 ng-if="prop.id">{{ prop.name.length > 20 ? prop.name.substring(0,20) + '...' : prop.name }}</h6></div>
```

Comment: Can you put this code in Fiddle or Codepen or Plunker with your code, it would be easy to play around with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind data dynamically to the future scope we can use $viewContentLoaded to notify a specific view has finished loading.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
  console.log(" viewContentLoaded fired ");
});
```

[Angular $viewContentLoaded event activoty range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496161/angular-viewcontentloaded-event-activoty-range)